# Incorrect graph export as PNG using macros on LibreOffice

Tags: graph, export, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am trying to export all charts on multiple sheet within my spreadsheet. I've looked some examples online to came up with a code that extracts all graphs within my file as PNGs. But I may be missing something, because every time I run this macro, some images are generated misaligned (and not the same, sometimes images are correct). This code is simple, but I don't what might be causing it. Could anyone help me solve this?

```
Sub ExportGraphs
    oDoc = ThisComponent

    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim eSheets As Object

    Dim args(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue

    gef = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicExportFilter")

    eSheets = oDoc.getSheets.createEnumeration()

    While eSheets.hasMoreElements
        oSheet = eSheets.nextElement()
        oDrawPage = oSheet.getDrawPage()
        iLimit = oDrawPage.getCount() -1

        For index = 0 to iLimit
            oDraw = oDrawPage.getByIndex(index)

            args(0).Name = "URL"
            args(0).Value = "file:///home/user_folder/Desktop/graphs/graph_" & oSheet.getName & "_" & index+1 & ".png"
            args(1).Name = "MimeType"
            args(1).Value = "image/png"

            gef.setSourceDocument(oDraw)
            gef.filter(args)

        Next
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe "misaligned". You could have a `FilterData` property in the `args` like here: http://www.ooowiki.de/DiagrammExport.html. With this further settings for the filter are possible. Unfortunately there seems to be no documentation for `FilterData` but  `.Name ="PixelWidth"` with value in pixel, `.Name ="PixelHeight"` with value in pixel, `.Name ="Quality"` with value 0 to 100 are also possible.

Comment: There also seems to be `LogicalWidth` and `LogicalHeight`.  Have a look at this example: http://openoffice.2283327.n4.nabble.com/GraphicExportFilter-with-openoffice-3-1-and-3-3-not-setting-DPI-td3310397.html

Comment: It seems that this was an issue with the libreoffice version I was using (version 4.0.6.2). Because when I ran this macro on Open Office 4.1.1, it was exported just fine.

Comment: When I said "mislaligned", I was trying to explain that somehow those graphs origin points (x,y) (0px,0px) were different than image export origin points (like (+4px,+5px)).

Answer (score 1):

Change: `MimeType` with `MediaType` in:

```
args(1).Name = "MimeType"
```